# How to delete specific rows in excel and upshift cells using a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me on removing specific rows in Excel and then shift cells up by using a macro?
E.g. I need to delete rows 8, 14 and 79.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Sorry i can't find something common about my question

Comment: You could just push the record button on the developer ribbon and delete the rows to later check the code. Did you even do that?

Comment: wow i had no idea about that. Thanks Damian, i know you were ironical but you really helped me. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped. I wasn't being ironical, is the first thing you should try.

Comment: I didn't know about it's existence. This will help me a lot about my future issues. Thanks Damian.

Comment: @Sakis After you used the Macro Recorder you will probably see a lot of `.Select` and `.Activate`. Read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to improve your recorded code to make it *much* faster, more realiable and a lot shorter.

Comment: I did read one post about deleting rows that suggested working from the bottom up - logic being that if you delete row 8 then what was row 24 is now row 23 etc...

Comment: @SolarMike Right you need to loop from bottom, or alternatively delete all rows at once (see answer below).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ok, so when all 3 are deleted at the same time it only re-numbers after that delete operation is complete : neat. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change sheet name if needed

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<- Find lastrow of column A where we assume data appears

        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1 '<- Loop from bottom to top
            If i = 8 Or i = 14 Or i = 79 Then '<- If row is 8 or 14 or 79
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete '<- Delete row
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Another Solution suggested by Pᴇʜ (see comments):**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("8:8,14:14,79:79").EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

**Another Solution:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Union(.Rows(8), .Rows(14), .Rows(79)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly for my purpose. Thank you so much for your help! I have no words to describe how much you've helped me with my project.

Comment: If you are hardcoding the rows anyway... why not `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("8,14,79").EntireRow.Delete`? You are taxing the execution time with a loop when there is no need to.

Comment: @Damian this will gives an error. if you are planning take any action in rows you should use .rows() instead of .range().

Comment: @Error1004 Use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("8:8,14:14,79:79").EntireRow.Delete` instead.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8,A14,A79").EntireRow.Delete` Anyway, my comment was about the 1 execution time vs the loop where you are hardcoding the rows.

Comment: @Error1004 Actually the critical point here is: You don't need to loop if you know the row number to delete! That's a waste of time. A loop is only needed eg. to check cell values for a criteria before delete.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i have edit my answer posting your answer too.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your suggestions! I really learnt a lot today.

Comment: @Error1004
I don't understand. I tasted it and worked great for 3 rows as your example. Now i've edited this including all rows i want to delete i take error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". Can you please tell me why this happens?

Comment: `Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Union(.Rows(8), .Rows(23), .Rows(25), .Rows(41), .Rows(65), .Rows(80), .Rows(82), .Rows(98), .Rows(122), .Rows(137), .Rows(139), .Rows(155), .Rows(179), .Rows(194), .Rows(196), .Rows(212), .Rows(236), .Rows(251), .Rows(253), .Rows(269), .Rows(293), .Rows(308), .Rows(310), .Rows(326), .Rows(350), .Rows(365), .Rows(367), .Rows(383), .Rows(407), .Rows(422), .Rows(424), .Rows(440), .Rows(464), .Rows(479), .Rows(481), .Rows(497)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With

End Sub
`